# Create PhoneGap 3.0.0 project error - 'platform add android' i not a node

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get setup with phonegap 3.0.0. I am totally new to phone app development....just fyi.

Per instructions on phonegap's site ([here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)), I am attempting the `"platform add android"` commmand from within my newly created project ("phonegaptest") and getting the following errror:

[image]

Found one other [instance of this on the web](https://github.com/mwbrooks/phonegap-cli/issues/105) and it was a path issue, I don't think mine is as I can type 'android' at the command prompt and it shows a list of valid commands.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of attempting the `platform add android` command as posted on phonegap's website, skip that line and go onto the next line and do: `phonegap build android`. Then it will work.

Comment: hmm doing this - it just uses a remote environment and i have to log myself in. How can i use local environment?

Comment: when I use the local build android command the test helloworld app is created in the android platform folder. nothing from my root www folder is being used. i am stuck updating the two www folders manually.; there doesn't seem to be a reason to even have the root www folder if this is the case?

Comment: this let me upload to adobe and get an .apk but it breaks phonegaps instructions because it does not create an android directory.

Comment: to run it locally run `phonegap local build android`