# cordova/phonegap does not make android directory

Tags: android, cordova

ant, java, node.js, phonegap, and my adobe account are all setup properly. The [getting started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) says I should be able to type:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
```

to create a phonegap project. This does not work but following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930362/create-phonegap-3-0-0-project-error-platform-add-android-i-not-a-node) instructions and doing:

```
phonegap build android
```

does eventually get me a .apk file. But the getting started guide tells me to open eclipse and navigate to the directory of my project and then set the subdirectory as /android. but /android does not get created when you do `phonegap build android` so I have nothing to work with.

How do I get phonegap to create the android directory? I am trying to finish the getting started guide instead of taking shortcuts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does seem like you are using PhoneGap 3.0 and for this version, eclipse is not required (only if you want to use it for coding - compared to PhoneGap 1.0-2.x where eclipse was used to compiled the app, for the latest version it is no longer a requirement).

1. To begin, you should use the `phonegap` command instead of the `cordova` command: `phonegap create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`
2. Then navigate to `/HelloWorld/` folder
3. You should see atleast these two key folders `/www` and `/platforms`. Inside `/www` is where you place your HTML files and codes, and `/platforms/android` gets generated when you compile the app with the following command: `phonegap build android`.

Note: Avoid making any direct changes to files inside `/platforms` except for config and manifest files. The other files are dynamically generated when you run the `build` command. All coding should take place within `/www`.

One more thing, use the 3.0.0 [Getting Started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview).

**---- February 2014 Update ----**

With the release of Cordova 3.3.0, it seems the PhoneGap team is trying to address the naming confusion. The documentations have been updated to recommend people using the `cordova` command instead. Do not use the <strike>`phonegap`</strike> command anymore.

Here is a fresh installation guide for a guaranteed trouble free set up:

1. Install Cordova (forget the name PhoneGap from now on). 
   For PC:

   ```
   C:> npm install -g cordova
   ```
2. From command prompt, navigate to the folder you want to create your project using:

   ```
   cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
   cd HelloWorld
   ```
3. Define the OS you want to suppport, we'll go with Android for this example:

   ```
   cordova platform add android
   ```
4. Install plugins (If needed). For example we want the following:

   ```
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
   ```
5. Finally, generate the app using:

   ```
   cordova build android
   ```

   or to directly install the app to your connected device:

   ```
   cordova run android
   ```

Here is a link to the <strike>PhoneGap</strike>Cordova 3.3.0 Documentation
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about cordova and/or phonegap commands. Now their docs tell us to use cordova but it seems more like an error. I was trying to find out more in blogs or updates but nobody is mentioning the switch. Cheers.

Comment: phonegap 3.3 uses `cordova platform add android`.  One can check using `cordova help`

Comment: Hello @quik_silv thanks for your input, the post has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you should be using `phonegap` instead of `cordova` to create the project folder structure.

```
phonegap create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
```

[image]

And secondly, please note that `build` command uses two way to build for any specific platform. One using the `phonegap build API (online)` using the below command

```
phonegap build android
```

and second one locally using below command,

```
phonegap local build android
```

[image]

So you should try to use the second command for creating the android specific folder and use it with eclipse. You can look for more details over here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

When you run the `build local` command, **android folder is created inside the platforms folder**, and ***you should always modify the code(html, js, css) on the www folder present outside the platforms folder***.
The changes will get reflected once you again run the `build` command. This helps you maintain single code base for multiple platform ( which is the basis aim of using Phonegap)

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note**: *you need to have latest android sdk tools (vs18) to run on Android SDK.*

Answer (score 1):

I have found this 
[Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio Documentation for CTP1.1 Last updated: May 29, 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675) .

Some of the content from the documentation as follows.

This release supports building apps for the following **device targets**:

**Android 4+ (4.4 providing the optimal developer experience)
iOS 6 & 7
Windows 8.0 (Store)
Windows Phone 8.0**

**Requirements:**
Windows 8.1

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Professional, Ultimate, or Premium with the following optional features installed:

Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8
Windows Phone 8.0 SDK

**Additional system requirements vary by device platform:**

The Android emulator works best with PCs capable of installing the Intel HAXM driver

Windows Phone 8 requires a Hyper-V capable PC to run the emulator
Building for iOS and using the iOS Simulator requires a Mac capable of running Xcode 5.1

**Third Party Dependencies :**

Joyent Node.js – Enables Visual Studio to integrate with the Apache Cordova Command Line Interface (CLI) and Apache Ripple™ Emulator
Git CLI – Required only if you need to manually add git URIs for plugins

Google Chrome – Required to run the Apache Ripple emulator for iOS and Android

Apache Ant 1.8.0+ – Required as a dependency for the Android build process

Oracle Java JDK 7 – Required as a dependency for the Android build process

Android SDK – Required as a dependency for the Android build process and Ripple

SQLLite for Windows Runtime – required to add SQL connectivity to Windows apps (for the WebSQL Polyfill plugin)

Apple iTunes – Required for deploying an app to an iOS device connected to your Windows PC

[image]