# Phonegap/Cordova not creating project

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I installed cordova/phonegap on 3 computers so far, and for some reason It's not working.
When I create a project following steps here:
   [cordova/phonegap does not make android directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923720/cordova-phonegap-does-not-make-android-directory) I just get "..." 3 dots and nothing happens, I waited for some time but nothing is showing up, any ideas? Nodejs is latest version and so is Cordova/phonegap