# Cordova files not downloading like previous versions

Tags: android, html, eclipse, mobile, cordova

Using eclipse with cordova and after the download of cordova files and extraction the files, the official documentation reads :

Copy **cordova-2.0.0.js** from your Cordova download earlier to assets/www

Copy **cordova-2.0.0.jar** from your Cordova download earlier to /libs

This was not included in the download and I have tried downloading other versions, does anybody know where I can find these files, I'm guessing there has been an update but the documentation hasn't been updated to let us know how to include these files. If there is away can someone explain in basic terms how to download and use the files, im new to all this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use cordova 2.0? The latest version is 3.0 and the installation method is completely different. With 3.0, Cordova is installed via NodeJS and compiling an APK is done via command line and not from Eclipse anymore. I have posted a little getting started guide here: [Cordova/phonegap does not make android directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923720/cordova-phonegap-does-not-make-android-directory/18971442#18971442)

Comment: it is recommended you should use cordova 2.9.0 ver atleast below is depricated no need of node.js in this version