# Error while executing command "phonegap build android" in cmd

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I've just installed Phonegap in my windows and created a helloWorld application. Now I want to create unsigned apk file for this. But there is no `android` platform in folder named platforms in the project directory.

That's why I reached [this SO link for solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923720/cordova-phonegap-does-not-make-android-directory)

Now I'm following one of the answers and trying to execute the command `phonegap build android`. But it is giving me following errors in cmd.

I've opened this commands as administrator.

Error log:

```
C:\Users\Kaushal28\Documents\ooo>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android ' ...
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kaushal28\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Unzipping C:\Users\Kaushal28\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-  all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to    C:\Users\Kaushal28\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-  all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh


Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip    file

    at    org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager. java:78)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)


Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)

    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)

    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)

    ... 3 more

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:   java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager. java:78)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
    at   org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager. java:65)
    ... 3 more
```

What is the solution for this? Or I'm doing something wrong? 
Thank you :)

Comment: If you dont have `android` folder into the platforms folder then you need to install it: `cordova add platform android`

Comment: @XristoEftimov  this gives error: `Error: Cordova does not know add; try cordova help for a list of all the available commands.`

Comment: @Kaushal28 I'm sorry, my fault :( `cordova platform add android` is correct

Comment: You can also use `phonegap build android`.
Because after this command phonegap uses the `cordova platform add android` command.

Comment: first remove the platform `cordova platform rm android` and again add platform.
It will works for you.