# phonegap doesn't generate platforms/android subdirectory?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Hi!

I've decided to try out phonegap but i am having trouble getting it set up with eclipse using the CLI as the guides seem to be outdated and inaccurate. Here's what i've done so far to get the phonegap project set up in eclipse:

- "phonegap create hello" to create a new phonegap project
- then i tried "phonegap platform add android", but gave me a 'is not a node' error
- from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930362/create-phonegap-3-0-0-project-error-platform-add-android-i-not-a-node) question i got the idea that i should instead use "phonegap build android", so i used that command.

According to the android platform guide in the official phonegap website it says that now there should be a platforms/android subdirectory in the phonegap project folder, but there isn't. The platforms folder is completely empty.

Have i missed something? Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try `phonegap install android`.

By just typing `phonegap` without any arguments you'll get the basic help and when you want to know more of a specific command do `phonegap help <subcommand>`

Personally I found the [Cordova CLI documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) to be a little more in depth and if you're just building locally you'll have no big difference between the `cordova` command and the `phonegap` command as far as I've been able to tell. You only really need the `phonegap` command if you're using PhoneGap Build as well.

Example:

```
% phonegap                                                                                                                                       
Usage: /usr/local/share/npm/bin/phonegap [options] [commands]

Description:

  PhoneGap command-line tool.

Commands:

  create <path>        create a phonegap project
  build <platform>     build a specific platform
  install <platform>   install a specific platform
  run <platform>       build and install a specific platform
  local [command]      development on local system
  remote [command]     development in cloud with phonegap/build
  help [command]       output usage information
  version              output version number

% phonegap help install                                                                                                                          

Usage: /usr/local/share/npm/bin/phonegap install [options] <platform>

Description:

  Installs the application for a specific platform.

  Automatically detects platform SDK support and uses the correct environment.

  See each environment for available [options].

Examples:

  $ /usr/local/share/npm/bin/phonegap install android
```

Comment: This doesn't work . using "phonegap install android", i get an error that there are no platforms added to this project.. and as i have said before, i have been unable to add a platform to a project. I've actually inspected the problem further and it seems i'm missing some folders in my cordova\3.1.0\bin\ directory. More specifically, "framework" and "create" folders.. The more general error i am receiving is "   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. The system c
annot find the path specified." I have chekced every bath and they seem to be ok .. dunno wats the problem

Comment: Have you tried removing the $HOME/.cordova folder? I had an issue with blackberry10 before where it fixed itself when I just removed the folder… When PhoneGap tries to install the platform it'll download a template project from the internet and maybe it got corrupted.

Comment: Also it might be worth checking your `$PATH` to see that the android tools are all available for the `phonegap` command.