# "cordova platform add" is not a command (Mac terminal)

Tags: android, macos, cordova

Ok so everything went down after I updated my Mac OS to 10.9.4

I have node, I have npm, cordova and everything. (versions: *node 0.10.33, npm 2.1.6, cordova 3.4.0-0.19.7*)
I can create a cordova project but I cannot add a platform (**ANDROID**).

Here are the contents of my ~/.bash_profile:

[image]

Note: the value of JAVA_HOME before was `/usr/libexec/java_home`

EDIT: I just changed the JAVA_HOME to `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contens/Home`

Here is the error the terminal is throwing:

`[error] 'platform add android' is not a /usr/bin/cordova command. See '/usr/bin/cordova help'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

It seems like the ANDROID SDK that I have linked in my bash_profile (*which already has everything installed*) is being overridden by the ANDROID SDK that I installed using brew which is located in **usr/local/bin**.

so whenever I type `cordova local build android` it is reading the one I installed using brew which doesn't have the proper SDKs installed.

Here are the steps I did to fix:

1. In my **Terminal** I went to usr/local/bin `cd /usr/local/bin`
2. I typed `android` to open *Android SDK Manager* that was installed using brew (*not the one in my Documents directory*)
3. I installed Android SDK Build-tools
4. I installed Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
5. After installation I went to the cordova project that I want to build and typed `cordova build android` and it worked.

**Note:** this is a temporary solution, to make it a permanent solution I had to remove the linking on the bash_profile to the sdk on my **/Documents** directory and replace with **/usr/local/bin**

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `cordova build android`

Look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930362/create-phonegap-3-0-0-project-error-platform-add-android-i-not-a-node)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I tried build but here is what I got:

`[ReferenceError: a is not defined]
[Error: Please install Android target 19 .. `

I tried typing "android" on terminal and installing all android sdk platforms but it's still saying the same error

Comment: You have cordova 3.4 version. Have you checked if the last version works? I'd try the lastest version ;)

Comment: thanks for this, using `cordova build android` helped me solve this problem by knowing the exact error.